# IntelliJ Idea - Мешающие всплывающие подсказки о параметрах методов

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как убрать такие подсказки? Они иногда пол-экрана занимают.

[image: Как убрать эти подсказки?]

Comment: 1) [Idea: Write and edit source code / Code reference information / Inlay hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inlay-hints.html#enable_inlay_hints)  2) [Webstorm: Write and edit source code / Code reference information / Method parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/viewing-method-parameter-information.html)